# Accuracy in approximation of series, up to 3 decimal places

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I really don't understand the type of question where you need to find how many terms of a series will guarantee a certain amount of accuracy. In both these examples, they want accuracy up to 3 decimal places. Yet they use 0.001 in the first question and 0.0005 in the second. I'm really confused, is one correct and one wrong? Please enlighten me. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're right that a given source should be consistent (these are from the same source, yes?). The phrase "to three decimal places" has to be given a rigorous mathematical meaning (it doesn't have one on its own). I think it's more common to use $0.0005$ with this phrase, but $0.001$ isn't unheard of by any means.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, these are from the same source, and in fact the same chapter - Barron's.