# what does it mean to have n-decimal accuracy?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am learning about alternating series. And one of the inequalities I have learned is $|S-s_n|\le a_{n+1}$, or in other words, the magnitude of the error that results from approximating $S$ (sum of a series) by $s_n$ (nth partial sum) is at most that of the first term that is not included in the partial sum.

A practice later asks me to find a partial sum that approximates $\ln2$ (sum of an alternating harmonic series) to **one decimal accuracy (nearest tenth)**.
The answer translates the question into the equation: $$|\ln2-s_n| \ge 0.05$$
But the question is why $0.05$?

BTW, from the inequality $|S-s_n|\le a_{n+1}$ ], we know that $|\ln2-s_n|<a_{n+1}$. Along with $|\ln2-s_n| \le 0.05$, how can we the know that [it is sufficient to choose] $a_{n+1} \le 0.05$?

Comment: No, $|\ln2-s_n|\le0.05$ !

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1712390/16397).